# How to redirect the root of a directory in .htaccess without also redirecting all the contents?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, directory, folder

I have two specific URL which are being redirected with 301 redirect in my .htaccess file like below:

```
redirect 301 /old-url-1/ http://www.domain.com/new-url-3/
redirect 301 /old-url-2/ http://www.domain.com/new-url-3/
```

Now problem is with URL structure like this:

`http://www.domain.com/old-url-1/sub-url/` or `http://www.domain.com/old-url-2/sub-url/` which is not getting to desired path on redirected url to 
`http://www.domain.com/old-url-1/sub-url/`.

How can I only match `/old-url-1/` part, and redirect in that case, in all other cases just follow original path like /old-url-1/sub-url/?

**Desired effect is like this:
If someone goes to:
`http://www.domain.com/old-url-1/` redirect visitor to `http://www.domain.com/new-url-3/`, but if someone goes to `http://www.domain.com/old-url-1/sub-url/`keep visitor on that URL, and don't redirect to `http://www.domain.com/new-url-3/sub-url`.

Comment: You made the question more complicated than the answer would be :_)

Comment: I agree with that :( That's why I added EDIT in bold.

Answer (score 2):

The key to redirect only exact URL match is to tell redirectMatch to match only exactly URL which is easy achieved with regex according to [httpd.apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), where description says:

> Description: Sends an external redirect based on a regular expression match of the current URL
>   Syntax:     RedirectMatch [status] regex URL

In my case,

```
redirect 301 /old-url-1/ http://www.domain.com/new-url-3/
```

Becames

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-url-1/$ http://www.domain.com/new-url-3/
```

Where `^`matches the beginning of URL, and `$` to match the end of URL.

So my rule only will match **old-url-1**, and not **old-url-1/sub-url** or some another **odl-url-1/some-sub-path**.

Comment: Because... `Redirect` is prefix matching (whole path segments) and appends everything after the match onto the destination URL. Whereas `RedirectMatch` is not, matching the _regular expression_ instead.